# Event handled 2 levels up

Tags: c#, wpf, oop, events, c#-4.0

In a WPF application (C#) I've got an instance of **ObjectX** in a class **ClassA**. This **ClassA** is instantiated in **ClassB**.

Hence **ClassB** -> *contains instance of* -> **ClassA** -> *which contains an instance of* -> **ObjectX**

**ObjectX** raises an **EventA**. I need to handle this event in ClassB.

What is this concept called (Event Delegation, Event Routing, ...)? And how can it be done?

Comment: Are your classes framework elements (controls)?

Comment: ObjectX is a FacebookClient Instance, ClassA is a custom Adapter class and ClassB is a WPF window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF it is called [Routed events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx), but this will work only if both of these are true:

1. We're speaking about element classes and 'contains' means that one of your control actually contain another [and `LogicalTreeHelper` states that your controls are parents/children to each other.
2. If the event you're looking for is defined as routed with correct routing strategy - either `tunelled` or `bubbling` will work. If it is not then routing events won't help you.

I have a feeling that all you need is something like this:

**in class B:**

```
this.instanceOfA.InstanceOfX.MyEvent += MyHandlerInClassB;
```

but this has nothing to do with WPF.

---

UPD: or something like this if you don't want to make instanceOfX accessible:

1. Define the same event on `classA` and raise it whenever `instanceOfX` raises its event
2. In `ClassB` handle `instanceOfA.MyEvent`

In this case you may keep `instanceOfX` private but you'll have to add one more event in the middle.

Comment: this.instanceOfA.InstanceOfX.MyEvent += MyHandlerInClassB; <- would work, however is this the clean implementation? I do not wish to reference InstanceOfX at all from ClassB, in other words I do not want it to be publicly accessible.

Comment: @Link- updated, unfortunately there is no way to make it really good if original event is not an instance of correct `RoutedEvent`. If it's not all you can do is to handle events in old fashion, making more or less objects public

Answer (score 0):

WPF has Routed Events:

> Invoke handlers on multiple listeners in an element tree, rather than
>   just on the object that raised the event.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx